# Is it a bad idea to populate properties inside constructor from database call?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class

```
public class Person {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public Person()
{

}

public Person(int id)
{
     //make database call and populate Person properties from id parameter
     var x = context.GetPersonDetails(id);
     Id = id;
     Name = x.Name;
     Address = x.Address;
     Phone = x.Phone;
}
```

Is this a bad practice to make database call inside constructor to populate properties? If yes, how do I get around this without the need to make a separate method to populate some class, because I would rather have

```
Person person = New Person(11);
```

instead of

```
Person person = New Person();
person = context.GetPersonDetails(11);
```

Comment: How about a static factory method? `Person person = Person.Load(context, 11)`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that's it's not great to put complex logic in your constructor. Use a factory or factory method instead.

Something like this:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    // Hide default constructor, we only want users going to the 
    // factory method
    private Person() { }

    // Factory method
    public static Person CreatePerson(int id)
    {
        // make database call and populate Person properties from id
        // parameter
        // Need to think how context is created...
        var x = context.GetPersonDetails(id);

        return new Person {
            Id = id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Address = x.Address,
            Phone = x.Phone
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first time I heard about factory, do you have a good link/article/example?

Answer (score 0):

In this way you are going to mess your data access logic with entity (which could be just dto). Some of your projects should reference entities assembly, but shouldn't reference DAL.

Answer (score 0):

Use [*Repository Pattern*](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/). The simplest and very short example can look like:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);
}

public class PersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
{
    public Person GetById(int id)
    {
       var x = context.GetPersonDetails(id);
       return new Person() { 
          // field properties from x
       };
    }
}
```

and usage by:

```
var personRepository = new Repository(...); // created and shared somewhere
```

and then simply:

```
var person = personRepository.GetById(id);
```